# Parsing nested JSON object with string name as a number instead of letter SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql, parsing

I ran into an issue trying to parse a nested JSON object that is a number and not a letter string. Here is what I am trying to parse:

```
Day": {
    "Hour": {
      "11": 5625.0751953125,
      "10": 1369.0666503906,
      "9": 20627.30078125,
      "8": 2088.8942871094
}

select *
from openjson(@json)
WITH(day nvarchar(100) '$.Day', hour nvarchar(100) '$.Day.Hour.11')
```

Error:

> Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 23
>   JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '1' is found at position 22.

There has to be a way to parse objects that begin with number. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Thanks!

Reference keys that contain non-alphanumeric characters in JSON text
Question. I have non-alphanumeric characters in keys in my JSON text. How can I reference these properties?+

Answer. You have to surround them with quotes in JSON paths. For example,

JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."$info"."First Name".value')

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server
Delete